# Secure aspx page from Cross Domain access in Azure Web App

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, azure, cors

I am using asp.net 3.5 web forms. I host my application to Azure.
I have an aspx which is having `WebMethod` and I call it with jquery `$.ajax` call from other `aspx` pages.
How do I protect my aspx to be accessed Only from my page and not from other applications?

Answer (score 0):

For Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgeries:

1.Write a GUID to your user's cookie.

2.Before your AJAX call, read this value out of the cookie and add it to the web request (post).

3.On the server side, compare the FORM value with the cookie value.

4.Because sites cannot read cookies from another domain, you're safe.

[Here is a good link.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!!! Just for clarification, a) I create a GUID and  b) Add it to jquery parameters and c) Save it to the user session for every request in order to c) validate it  to my web method (server site)?